# How to estimate thermal impedance of a closed aluminum chassis?

Tags: thermal, cooling

I am contemplating whether or not I need chassis perforations for heat dissipation in a project. The box is roughly 440 mm wide, 280 mm deep and 85 mm high (2 rack height units aluminum enclosure.)

The continuous TDP is 40W originating from spread out sources. There is some direct contact between the chassis side profiles and a metal mounting plate, which carries the electronics. The contact is through several (~8) short bolts of about 4mm diameter. Otherwise, the thermal dissipation is mainly through the interior air.

I could estimate the internal temperature rise if I knew the thermal impedance of such a closed chassis but after searching a bit, I have found no clues. I am looking for a ballpark number such as 1 K/W (fine) or is it more like 10 K/W (insufficient).

I also don't have much experience with closed chassis. A similar power project in a similar perforated chassis (with no intentional cooling) didn't even get warm to the touch.

Comment: Put a heater inside it, run it continuously until you reach steady state, measure the temperature and then calculate the delta to ambient and divide by power?

Comment: @winny I don't have the case. I want to estimate whether I should discuss/order a closed/perforated option with the manufacturer. But I could do this with a similar sized boxed. Probably the safest way. But I was looking for experiences regardless.

Comment: I would estimate closer to 10 than 1 K/W for that geometry.

Comment: @tobalt What's the ambient temperature that this box is radiating into? Are you familiar with Stefan-Bolzmann and how it may apply here?

Comment: @jonk The ambient temperature is 5 - 40 °C (room temperature). The external dissipation will be dominated by passive convection and/or conduction. Radiation will be irrelevant at this temperature range.

Comment: @tobalt I believe radiation will be worth a look-see. But if you are sure about the irrelevance, then that's the end of the discussion.

Comment: 40W in a 440x280x85mm box is a lot. In practice, the box will have another appliance sitting on top, or a stack of magazines, or a cat, so only the sides will be available for dissipation. Vents aren't just for airflow, they also dissuade the user from stacking too much stuff on top.

Comment: @jonk I just did the maths for dissipation via radiation and it is indeed more than I thought, but only really starts to become efficient when the case temperature is 50°C ish. So trusting on bobflux' experience I believe that 40W is too much for a realistic usecase without ventilation.

Comment: Also with vents you get "chimney effect" (draft) inside the box, without vents you don't so I have doubts about internal convection flow being enough to move heat from the boards to the bow where it can escape... Maybe it works, who knows, but it sounds a bit risky.

Comment: @tobalt I'd like to see your calcs. If you feel you want to expose them. Bear in mind that since everything is inside a case, it is effectively an integration sphere so emissivity can be assigned 1 for the interior (including air's radiation effects inside the box.) What starts to matter is the case itself and its thermal conductivity to the outside surface (and how you color the outside surface to optimize its radiation.) In any case, I'll leave this to you. I think this may help to explain your experience mentioned at the end of your post. But I'm frankly done pushing the issue.

Comment: @jonk Aha, I think I finally realize.. are you talking about the thermal radiation being an efficient coupling between the internal electronics and the chassis ? I interpreted your first post as dealing with *external* radiative cooling, hence my reply about 50°C, because only a small fraction of solid angle (~1 sr) and surface area (~0.1 m²) contribute to *external* radiative cooling. Internally, you are right, radiation seems quite powerful to equilibrate temps between chassis and electronics. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @jonk Convection will dominate over radiation at those low delta temperatures.

Comment: @tobalt Yes, that's what I wanted you to consider. The interior is just an integrating cavity and so everything has an emissivity of 1, regardless of its shape or material. Over time, the details don't matter. The effect is the same. The only thing that then matters is how heat moves from the interior surface of the box to the exterior surface of the box (conduction) and is then radiated. (It will also absorb from the surrounding environment, too, not to be discounted either.) It's often worth a calc or two just to see where this is going.

Comment: I agree that 40W is quite a lot for natural convection inside the box. Conduction thru the suspension is quite low. In closed chassis without forced convection usually you try to couple the thermal load to one side of the box and eventually heat sink that externally (think old power supplies)

Comment: @tobalt [This](https://www.engineeringenotes.com/thermal-engineering/heat-conduction/conduction-of-heat-through-a-sphere-thermal-engineering/30154) is roughly the direction I'd take to make a few back-of-envelope calcs, but using knowledge you haven't disclosed about your case. In the end, that doesn't mean I'd disagree with other thoughts here. It just means I'd want to estimate this value and consider if it is worth pushing a little by changing the exterior's ability to radiate. Perhaps not. But I'd want to check. If for no other reason, to document in a binder that the idea was considered.

Comment: Off the cuff I'd say closer to 1 than 10. That said, 1 K/W is getting a bit magic. Surface finish and air flows matter. The whole topic is something of a black art. You can use formulae to calculate convection and radiation losses. You may even get it right. But a simple model would be easy and allows you to do various "what it's" with ease. || A fan may be unacceptable but even a small one can make a vast difference

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon I have planned for a small fan anyway. Whether it will need to run or not... that is something for another day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the following approach: You can calculate the thermal resistance of convection on a heated wall as

\$R_{th} = \frac{1}{A \cdot h}\$

where A is the wall surface and h is the heat transfer coefficient. In case of natural convection you set the value of h dependent on wall angle and wall temperature, typically in a range between 5 and 8 for electronic heat sink problems.

Now with two side walls with \$\frac{1}{A_Side1} = 26.7\$, \$\frac{1}{A_Side2} = 42.0\$ and the top wall with \$\frac{1}{A_top} = 8.1\$ and an approximated h = 5 (kind of conservative), you can calculate the wall's thermal resistances of convection: \$R_{th,wall,Side1} = 5.3\$, \$R_{th,wall,Side2} = 8.4\$, \$R_{th,wall,top} = 1.6\$

Looking at an individual wall, you have convection internally, conduction through the wall, and convection outside. Since the wall is aluminium, the conduction resistance can be neglected, and so so can in good approximation double the resistances to get the total resistance of the wall as

\$R_{th,Side1} = 10.6\$, \$R_{th,Side2} = 16.8\$, \$R_{th,top} = 3.2\$

Assuming that the bottom wall sits on ground and does not contribute to heat dissipation, the whole box resistance is

\$\frac{1}{R_{th,box}} = \frac{2}{R_{th,Side1}} + \frac{2}{R_{th,Side2}} + \frac{1}{R_{th,top}} =  \frac{2}{10.6} + \frac{2}{16.8} + \frac{1}{3.2}\$

\$R_{th,box} = 1.6 \frac{K}{W}\$

If the internal power is 40 W, then the air internally is about 64 K higher than outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will have to do some detailed checks and repeat your calcs for myself (to fully comprehend them) but it looks a nice instruction.om how to estimate this kind of problem. In addition, internal radiation also contributes as suggested by jonk. I have moved on in the meantime and planned for active cooling anyway, but I might close the perforations for a test and see how hot it gets.

Comment: This procedure is usually confirmed by my CFD simulations. The outside surface temperature, which is relevant for radiation (which I did not take into account here), is increased by 32 K as compared to ambient. Internal radiation depends a lot on the usually complex internal geometry, and might be not be dominating here because all internal surfaces will be on not too different temperatures. If there are openings in the box, the model becomes a lot more complex and I prefer to employ CFD instead.