# How to estimate the temperature rise in an enclosed space due to power dissipation?

Tags: temperature, power-dissipation

I am planning a battery maintenance system that discharges a battery to a storage-compatible state of charge if the battery is not used for some time.

I would ideally like to dissipate 4kWh over 15 days --> 11W. I am considering dissipating the power using a 50W resistor.

Assuming that the power dissipation resistor is inside an enclosed compartment, how would I go about estimating the steady-state temperature inside the compartment? For argument's sake, let's assume a plastic ABS pox plastic box 30cm x 20cm x 15 cm with a wall thickness of 2 mm.

Comment: Does the box need to be sealed waterproof? Can it be metal? Can you ventilate it?

Comment: Maybe this question and its answers/comments give you some insight: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/588636/237061

Comment: @tobalt Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for! Voted to close the question as duplicate of linked question.

Comment: @DDuck In a first approximation I wanted to look at a unventilated, closed, plastic box but I may need to adjust if it proves unfeasible.

Comment: That's quite a large box and 11W is not all that much. Seat of pants estimate 10-20°C rise or so. It's easiest to mock it up and test it rather than using rough estimates or CFD. There are also some very unreliable 'calculators' online, suggest avoiding.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's a good point...

Comment: @ARF regarding Uwe's answer in the linked question. In practice, with perforations and no active cooling enabled, internal temperature rise turned out to be approximately 15 K. So I guess his estimate of 60 K for a closed box sounds realistic, maybe slightly on the high side. Just to help judging the relevance of the information there.

Comment: @tobalt Thanks for the hint. I was already expecting that the rule-of-thumb estimations are likely to be on the high side. Sounds like I will make a mock-up of my box...

Comment: Gotta remember that the tungsten in sealed container dissipating 11 W (aka a light bulb) reaches 2500 K